# Как передать диапазон ячеек в качестве параметра функции в Apps Script

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Мне нужно произвести какую то операцию над диапазоном ячеек (например А1:А10). Есть функция getRange() и вроде бы всё просто, но что если количество строк в таблице будет меняться и например диапазон изменится.

Пробовал так:

```
functon sumElements (range) {
 let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 let currSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 let dinamicRange = ss.getRange(range).getValues;

}
```

но компилятор ругается на параметр range в getRange()

Comment: Суть вопроса непонятна. Дополните его, чтобы не было гаданий.

Answer (score 0):

Все прекрасно работает, если исправить ошибки:

1. Не `functon`, а `function` (допускаю опечатку)
2. Не `ss.getRange(range)`, а `currSheet.getRange(range)`
3. После `.getValues` нужны скобки `()`

таким образом код выглядеть должен так:

```
function sumElements (range='A1') {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let currSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let dinamicRange = currSheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  Logger.log(dinamicRange);
}
```

ну и в качестве аргумента вы можете передавать свой диапазон. Пример вызова из другой функции:

```
function start () {
  sumElements('A1:A10');
}
```

### UPD

Если вы хотите передавать диапазон из самой таблицы в качестве параметра, то в принципе не нужно `.getRange(range)`, `range` уже будет содержать массив с переданными данными. Далее можете проводить с ним необходимые действия:

```
function sumElements (range) {
  const arr = range.map((x) => x * 2);
  return arr;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовал так сделать непосредственно в самой таблице прописав в ячейке функцию =sumElements(A1:A10) и всё равно выдаёт ошибку Range not found :( Почему то диапазон ячеек переданный извне не понимается скриптом :(.

Comment: @DmitrySalnikov дополнил ответ